# what is the problem with using strided stream access to measure peak memory bandwidth

Tags: memory, benchmarking, cpu-architecture, microbenchmark

Using Skylake as an example, its cache line is 64B.

I tried to write a simple program to see what is the peak memory bandwidth I can consume. In the code below, I intentionally make the stride 64B so that each load would fetch a different cache line (64B).  I collect the time used to finish 10M loads and then calculate the memory loaded by multiplying the number of loads with 64B.

Then I start threads which synchronize ad run the code below in parallel. So when all the threads finish, the total memory loaded is **total * NUM_OF_THREADS * 64B**. Then I divide it with (end_time-start_time).

THe bandwidth I got is much higher the theoretical peak memory bandwidth for Skylake. So it is not correct. But I don't know what is wrong with my calculation.

The only guess I can make is that, maybe the memory BW is not saturated, the processor prefetches the following cache lines so that many of the loads actually load from the cache. But since my inline assembly is a dense sequence of memory loads, I am not sure how to confirm my guess.

Any comment? Thank you.

```
   st = start_timing()
        do {
          for (i=0; i< 10; i++) {
            asm volatile("movl 0x0(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x40(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x80(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0xc0(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x100(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x140(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x180(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x1c0(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x200(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x240(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x280(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x2c0(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x300(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x340(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x380(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x3c0(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x400(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x440(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x480(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                         "movl 0x4c0(%[P]),%[sum]\n\t"
                             : [P]"+r"(p), [sum]"+r"(sum)
                             : );
          }   
          total += 200;
          p = q+ ((total%1000000)<<6);

        } while (total < 10000000);
    et = end_timing()

    bw = (total * 64)/(et-st)
```

Comment: What actual numbers are you getting?  What do you see with `perf stat` to count cache misses?

Comment: I use perf to measure the actual memory bandwidth consumption to be around 95GB/s. But my calculation mentioned in the original post gives more than 600GB/s. :)

Comment: You can measure the number of cache hits at each level using the performance events `MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L1_HIT`, `MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L2_HIT`, and `MEM_LOAD_RETIRED.L3_HIT`. I guess you're getting many L1 hits, but it's difficult to tell why without seeing the whole code. What did you mean by "I use perf to measure the actual memory bandwidth consumption to be around 95GB/s"? Like how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, dword loads from each cache line is a good way to benchmark cache / memory bandwidth for caches other than L1d.  (If data stays hot in L1d, you need to measure the bottleneck of getting it through load execution units into registers;  unless you have AVX512 it takes multiple instructions to read a whole cache line.)

Probably you're getting L1d or L2 cache hits.  If you never wrote the memory, it will all be copy-on-write mapped to the same physical zero page if it's in the BSS or allocated with malloc.

Or simply that different cores have their own private L1d caches.  See [How can cache be that fast?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329789/how-can-cache-be-that-fast) over on electronics.SE.  However, if you're actually touching 10MB of physical RAM, that's more than a quad-core SKL desktop has.  If you have a Skylake Xeon with more L3 cache, then yes the aggregate bandwidth can of course be significantly higher than RAM.

Also, http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/ shows that L3 replacement is not strictly pseudo-LRU; it's adaptive in recent Intel so it might be more resistant than you'd expect to eviction from looping over RAM.  10MB might be small enough to get some L3 hits with an 8MB total L3 on a quad-core i7.

---

`asm volatile` will stop it from getting optimized away, and a `"+r"(pointer)` input should be ok for seeing your pointer updates.  The compiler doesn't "know" that the asm reads the pointed-to memory (because you haven't told it that, and there's no `"memory"` clobber), so any earlier stores into the buffer could be optimized away as dead stores.

Comment: I double checked the final assembly and my inline assembly stays intact. I don't really initialize (or store to) the array ('q') since you can see that I just stride-read through it.

Comment: Isn't that  I think I am touching 10M * 64B = 640BM of memory due to the stride access?

Comment: @yeeha: oh, I didn't read the question carefully enough.  I missed that it was 10M loads, not 10MiB of buffer size.  But I think not initializing your array explains your observations.  You'll get TLB misses but data-cache hits if all pages are COW mapped to the same physical pages.